# Using simple-peer, peer.on('data') calls repeatedly

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io, webrtc, simple-peer

I am using `simple-peer` library for making a chat application.
When I receive message from the other peer connection using `peer.on('data' => (data) => { console.log(data) })`, it is called multiple times and I receive the message multiple times.

Comment: Where are you calling `peer.on()`? Is it in a `useEffect()` hook?

Comment: No, I have called it outside.

Comment: Are you using function components? Is the call part of a callback, or is it just something that's in your function? If it's the latter, `peer.on()` will be called on every render.

Comment: Ok thanks @Calvin . I am actually using ```peer.on()``` inside a functional component.